# why the sampling proprety of dirac function gives this?

Tags: mathematical-expressions, mupad

In MuPAD I simplify:

```
simplify(2*t*dirac(t+1))
```

Which gives :

```
-2*dirac(t + 1)
```

I know that

```
f(t)*dirac(t-k)=f(k)*dirac(t)
```

so `f(t)=2*t` , `dirac(t+1)=dirac(t-(-1))` so that means `k=-1`
So `2 * t * dirac(t+1) =2*(-1)*dirac(t) =-2*dirac(t)` which is different than what MuPAD returns, `-2*dirac(t + 1)`.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. It is not

```
f(t)*dirac(t-k)=f(k)*dirac(t)
```

but

```
f(t)*dirac(t-k)=f(k)*dirac(t - k)
```

The reason is simple: By pointwise multiplying with a function you cannot move the position at which the Dirac has its spike. If it was at t = k, it must remain at t = k after.